# Forge DWG Pack and Go Translation

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm having some issues when translating the IDW to a DWG. I'm using the created configuration file from Inventor which works fine when translating one file and is saved as *.dwg which becomes available for download. The problem occurs when changing the transmittal value to "yes" in the config file to handle multiple sheets and create a zip.

```
[12/02/2021 17:12:20] Start upload phase.
[12/02/2021 17:12:20] Error: Non-optional output [exportDWG.zip] is missing.
[12/02/2021 17:12:20] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase Publishing of job.
[12/02/2021 17:12:20] Job finished with result FailedMissingOutput
```

This fails during the upload phase as per the log info above and returns an error due to the missing zip file even after updating the code to reference the zip file. The zip file is created when debugging locally with the AppBundle.

I would like to have the created zip file available for download instead of the single dwg.

Comment: Did you set `zip` to true in your activity ? can you please paste your activity and workitem payload here ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Madhukar. 

I ended up exporting to a folder and zipping that up for download. Seems to do the trick.